# How do I override the precedence of a header file when using pybind11 and cmake?

Tags: python, c++, header-files, pybind11

I have a header file called `node.h` within my C++ project, where I am now writing python bindings. Within python, there is also a header file called [`node.h`](https://github.com/python/typed_ast/blob/master/ast27/Include/node.h). I am creating my Python bindings with PyBind11 and CMake similar to:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(WeatherRouting)
message("Configuring WeatherRouting (python package)")

set(PYBIND11_CPP_STANDARD -std=c++17)

find_package(Python COMPONENTS Interpreter Development)
find_package(pybind11 CONFIG)
include_directories(${ROUTINGLIB_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES})

file(GLOB_RECURSE SRC_FILES CONFIGURE_DEPENDS LIST_DIRECTORIES false ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src *.cpp *.cc)

pybind11_add_module(_WeatherRouting SHARED ${SRC_FILES})
target_link_libraries(_WeatherRouting PRIVATE RoutingLib)
set_target_properties(_WeatherRouting PROPERTIES POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE TRUE)
```

And this is causing the header file in python being used, over my header file, when I include my header file like:

```
#include "node.h"
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Where exactly is this `node.h` header file that you *want* to include? Especially, what is the full relative path from the source file that does the `#include`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The file I want to include it from is called `edge.h` and `node.h` is within the same directory, at the same level. So i guess, `../node.h`? I am new to cpp

Comment: If `edge.h` and `node.h` are in the *same* directory, then `#include "node.h"` should work, as that should always look in the same directory first. If it's in the *parent* directory then use `#include "../node.h"`.

Comment: To avoid issues like this you usually introduce a package-dependent prefix to be able to write includes like `#include "mylib/node.h"`...

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude hmm strange, they are definitely at the same level. I think I will restructure the project to be able to do the suggestion by fabian. Thanks.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude -- "always look in the same directory first" -- it's not quite that simple. The Standard simply says that `#include "XXX"` searches "in an implementation-defined manner", and if that fails, searches again as if the directive had been `#include <XXX>` (where the mechanics is, again, implementation-defined). It's traditional to look first in the "current directory", but that has different interpretations; some compilers would look in the directory where `edge.h` was found, and some would look in the directory where the .cpp file being compiled was found.